# How to correctly load this jquery script through the file functions.php?

Tags: javascript, wp-enqueue-script, jquery-ui

i'm trying to include and correctly load the script goo.gl/QlJxbk on this wordpress website.
I followed the doc http://webtechfreaky.github.io/Cloud-Pricing-Slider/docs/index.html to load correctly the script but as you can see something isn't working/loading correctly.
As reported in the docs, the script have 2 columns, the right colum load correctly, the left column didn't, the preset selector stop to work, price is out of line and so on.

What i did is: load the script folder inside the folder theme, then enqueue CSS and Script on the file functions.php of the theme with following commands:

For the styles // Pricing slider style

```
    wp_enqueue_style( 'jquery-ui-full-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/layout/assets/css/jquery-ui.min.css' , array(), '', 'all' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'qs-slider-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/layout/assets/css/slider.min.css' , array( 'jquery-ui-full-style' ), '', 'all' );
```

and for the scripts // Pricing slider script

```
        wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-1.11.0', get_template_directory_uri() . '/layout/assets/js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js', array(), '', true );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui', get_template_directory_uri() . '/layout/assets/js/jquery-ui.js', array(), '', true );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui-min', get_template_directory_uri() . '/layout/assets/js/jquery-ui.min.js', array(), '', true );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'qs.slider.init', get_template_directory_uri() . '/layout/assets/js/qs.slider.init.js', array(), '', true );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'qs.slider', get_template_directory_uri() . '/layout/assets/js/qs.slider.js', array(), '', true );
```

Probably something is in conflict, or the array are not correctly declared, i'm not really able to figure what is going wrong on here.
Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to include `jquery-ui` and `jquery-ui.min` either of them is sufficient . Also `jquery` and `jquery-ui` are already included in WordPress.

Try this

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery');   
wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui-core');   
wp_enqueue_script( 'qs.slider', get_template_directory_uri() . '/layout/assets/js/qs.slider.js', array('jquery','jquery-ui-core'), '', true );    
wp_enqueue_script( 'qs.slider.init', get_template_directory_uri() . '/layout/assets/js/qs.slider.init.js', array('jquery','jquery-ui-core'), '', true );
```

The above code will make sure `jquery` and `jquery-ui` is loaded before loading your slider.

Load the styles as you're already doing.

Please note that only loading these files will not do anything on its own you need to actually use the HTML markup provided by the author of this slider, refer to [this](https://github.com/webtechfreaky/Cloud-Pricing-Slider/blob/master/index.html) source code. And customize the slider as per your needs and then add to your custom page.

Comment: With the modify that you suggested, all elements of the slide disappeared, there's only txt elements.
I referred to the source code in HTML, author said to include line 49 > 150 and thats what i did, but this slide keep not loading properly.

Comment: Load the HTML markup where you're trying to show the slider, e.g. in a post edit screen click on `text` besides the `visual` tab and then add the HTML there, it should output the required slider in your post .

Comment: Before my modify, was the slider appearing ?

Comment: Yes, the slider loaded every "slide", but with some elements out of row. What you mean exactly for the HTML markup? Can you exactly refer lines of code of this source code? https://github.com/webtechfreaky/Cloud-Pricing-Slider/blob/master/index.html
I've copied and pasted those lines https://github.com/webtechfreaky/Cloud-Pricing-Slider/blob/master/index.html#L48-L166

Comment: Thats how i see the slide now https://s27.postimg.org/jf95ro4jn/Screenshot_from_2017_02_12_00_14_53.png and  that's how should be https://raw.githubusercontent.com/webtechfreaky/Cloud-Pricing-Slider/master/preview.png

Comment: I saw the screenshot, This will be probably be due to your theme, because themes also load there own styles, this might be conflicting with your slider. Also if you're uncomfortable with PHP and HTML, you should not edit the PHP files, consider using a slider or a pricing plugin, there are plenty available on the WordPress plugin repository, just search for 'WordPress pricing plugin'.

Comment: Even if you manage to make this slider look like the one you want, it won't actually work, your website users will not be able use it because it's values never get saved. To save it's values custom PHP functions are required.

Comment: What you need is a custom plugin implementation of this slider for WordPress.  Which is off topic and it requires knowledge of PHP and HTML, so please close this question and accept the answer if this is the case.

Comment: Then this slide on which kind of site could works?Because i saw other worpress sites loading their own styles that have slide like this
Best solution would be a slide like that at the end of the page https://www.planethoster.net/fr/Serveurs-HybridCloud

As you can see for what i have to do i can't use a pricing plugin because users have to build their own package and then pay with bitcoin and another cryptocurrency.
Which kind of solution you could suggest a part this slide? Bootstrap?
Thanks for helping!

Comment: I would suggest you to browse [themeforest](https://themeforest.net/category/wordpress/technology/hosting) for hosting related WordPress themes, these themes usually have functionality like you want, they are not free but they come with customer support so if you have any problems in future you can directly contact the developer and they will be able to help you.

Comment: The original question was how to load jquery scripts correctly and I've provided answer to that. However, how to create this slider and how to use it or what else to use is a different question. Please close this question first and then ask another question in a different post.

Comment: The original question was how to load jquery scripts correctly and you provided an answer that make the script works badly than before, without loading handles and other components of the script. 
Thanks for your help but the problem is still there, than sorry but don't understand  why i should close the question if my  problem is still unresolved. Going buy a paid plugin (the same FYI is paid plguin too https://codecanyon.net/item/cloud-pricing-slider/9827795) could be a valid option but is not a working answer to my problem.

Comment: Exactly my point, the scripts are loading correctly but the problem is because of themes style.css messing with your slider. Or any other plugin styles. Best option for you is to use the paid plugin.

Comment: I check the  link to the plugin you provided is not for wordpress and was last updated in 2014 you should probably not use it because it's too old. And potentially have vulnerabilities.

Comment: Ok thanks i'll wait some other contributions on fix the layout problem, (because the plugin load on wordpress as you can see http://solarflarecoin.us/js , the problem is only in the layout) otherwise i'll close the question.